# Scanning the Articles on Web

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I want to make an app that would function something like Summly mobile app.
Can you please tell me:

1. How do I scan the web (a set of online resources) to extract the text
2. Which tools I have to use?
3. Recommend few good practical sources (please without theory - I have found those type of books as well)

The reason fo doing this - to delve more from practical aspect into the field of machine learning.

Thx!

Comment: I have to start somewhere with the search. And online I did not found these answers. Can anyone give some practical examples?

Answer (score 1):

Data acquisition in such apps is basically trivial - one usually have a (fixed) list of source urls, and retrieve data from them using standard functions that implement web-requests, specifically HTTP GET (they are language specific but avaliable in most languages nowdays). One then parse HTML with some HTML parsing library like [Agility pack for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691119/Html-Agility-Pack-Massive-information-extraction-f) and retrieve requried articles using hand-designed XPath queries. That does not require any machine learning at all.

The number of possible tools and approaches to use is enormous, one can create something Summly-like by stacking up simple data downloader like above and some open-source summarization tool (these can be found by googling "automatic summarization" and "automatic summarization libraries") or by calling some online summarization API, without any knowledge of machine learning and language processing. The question is simple too broad, you should somehow narrow your goals.